# Is it possible to get full list of countries within selected google maps route?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am now starting new project and I wanted to know if I could use google maps to solve my problem and get list of countries in selected route.

I tried to search on internet about this but couln't find anything what I needed.

Edit: So I created function which loops through routes steps and by given latitude/longitude coordinates in each step I can get in which country is this step taken by using googles geocoder.geocode function. But now I face new problem while I am looping through steps I get this error: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT indicates the webpage has sent too many requests within the allowed time period.
I even tried to set timeout for 500ms before caling geocode function but no use.

Answer (score -1):

If you do a route request, it will always have details about crossing international boundaries.

Just try doing a from/to request on maps.google.com and you will see in the directions, when it crosses a border.

That same information is available to us to take from the [direction response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#InspectingResults).