# Is it possible to get list of countries within selected google maps route?

Tags: java, android, routes, maps

As the questions says I deliberately asked this question in the same form that was already asked here on stackoverflow but it was 6 years ago and I wonder if there is any other better way to find all the countries that the routes goes through asides from answers in those questions:

[Is it possible to get full list of countries within selected google maps route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184664/is-it-possible-to-get-full-list-of-countries-within-selected-google-maps-route)

[Google Maps Javascript API, DirectionsService, list of countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923710/google-maps-javascript-api-directionsservice-list-of-countries)

Using Google Maps API or any other...

Comment: What have you found on the official Google Maps documentation? I assume you looked there thoroughly, right? :)

Comment: Each leg consists of a set of steps. Each step has a lat/long. Iterate over each step, then do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497728/get-country-from-latitude-longitude

Comment: Yes this is what the other answers are saying as well but there is so many steps in each query that any geocoding api will say OVER_QUERY_LIMIT or something similar...

Comment: Then 1) pay for it 2) find another API or 3) Import the data into your application and perform the checks yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959218/latitude-longitude-dataset-for-country-borders